# If Captain Lorca arranged the prison transport incident, is he responsible for the pilot’s death?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery, captain-lorca

In [Star Trek Discovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Discovery) [S1:E3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_Is_for_Kings) - *Context is for Kings*, we see a prison transport [accident](https://www.vox.com/2017/10/1/16387154/star-trek-discovery-s1-ep-3-recap).

In this we see the death of the pilot of the prison transport.

It has been claimed that Lorca probably [arranged](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/173030/did-captain-lorca-arrange-the-prison-transport-incident-in-context-is-for-kings?noredirect=1#comment464949_173030) this accident in order to get Burnham [aboard](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/170959/161) his ship.

My question is: **If Captain Lorca arranged the prison transport incident, is he responsible for the pilot’s death?**

EDIT: I don't believe this is a duplicate question because the other question doesn't talk about Lorca's intent and culpability in the primary question. That is just left open to the answerer's interpretation.

Comment: ..well, *obviously*, who else?! That is assuming the pilot [**actually died**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/171028/57069)....did we see an *actual* death?

Comment: If he did indeed arrange it (and that was my initial impression), then he must have known death of, or injury to, the pilot was at least a possibility, and perhaps he even bargained on it (a living pilot might have been able to effect a repair, or diverted the craft to a different destination). His actions later in the series do nothing to dissuade me of that impression. In fact, at the time, Michael's expression suggestion that she realised the whole thing was staged, however, since she's never mentioned it to Lorca, maybe she was just resigned to her fate and doesn't suspect anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Did the pilot survive?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/170967/did-the-pilot-survive)

Comment: Definitely not a dup. These question are about two different things.

Comment: @amflare - The other question asks "Did the shuttle pilot die or survive? And was their death or survival part of Lorca’s plan?".

Comment: The other Q/A focuses on the death/survival of the pilot. This Q/A focuses on the plan of Lorca. And when in doubt, look at the answers. That answer doesn't answer this question. Therefore, not a dup.

Comment: @amflare - The other question asks that very thing in the quote from the question body.  The abbreviated question in the subject line ("Did the pilot survive?") isn't as clear, but I assume that's a courtesy to avoid spoilers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is actually no evidence, one way or the other, that the pilot is actually dead or even injured. We can take the scene at face-value, of course; but if we assume that Lorca engineered the entire scenario, then it's altogether possible that the pilot was basically performing a stunt, and is alive and well.